# scipy BLAS routine does not overwrite input despite using overwrite_a=True

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython, blas

I am used to using BLAS routines in cython (from `scipy.linalg.cython_blas`), where the input is very often modified in place (for example, in the [dger](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-ger#26A7BEFC-1A1D-4C19-B482-5E72E6B02417) routine).
I'm trying to do the same with `scipy.linalg.blas.dger`, but despite using `overwrite_a=True`, `a` is untouched

(`dger` performs a rank one update, meaning `a + np.outer(x, y)`)

```
In [29]: x = np.array([1, 0, 2])

In [30]: y = np.array([-1,  1,  0,  2])

In [31]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)

In [32]: a + np.outer(x, y)
Out[32]: 
array([[-1,  2,  2,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 6, 11, 10, 15]])

In [33]: dger(1.0, x, y, a=a, overwrite_a=True)
Out[33]: 
array([[ -1.,   2.,   2.,   5.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  6.,  11.,  10.,  15.]])

In [34]: a  # still the original value
Out[34]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

What use is `overwrite_a=True` then ? And how can I perform the update in place ?

**EDIT**: I know that BLAS routines are in Fortran so `a` should be in Fortran order, but even changing this does not change `a`.

Comment: The overwriting is not guaranteed because f2py might copy the original array to pass to the blas routine. That's why you get the identifier *might* in the docs of many scipy routines

Comment: @percusse thanks a lot, it was not included in the dger routine. Would you happend to have a detailed resource to point me to, regarding scipy's handling of blas/lapack routines ?

Comment: It's mostly us wrapping them. Recently we have completed the BLAS collection on SciPy v1.0. This issue [recently came up](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5739) again. I guess I have to write something up :) No promises though it's getting tougher to spare time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite interesting: it's because

- `a` needs to be Fortran ordered because the output of dger, a Fortran routine, is.
- `a.dtype` is `np.int64`, so dger does not want to change its type to `np.float64` and does not overwrite it.

Comment: I tried with `a` Fortran ordered and as `np.float64` with no replacement occuring. Did you get successfully `a` modified with these changes?

Answer (score 1):

The low-level blas routines are wrapped with [f2py](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/).

The arguments `overwrites_X` are hints to f2py (see the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/signature-file.html) and search for overwrite) that the routine *may* use the memory of `X` as it sees fit (it might use the space as a scratch array and not specifically do what `out=` does in other routines). It might as well not use it.

The documentation for the low-level [dger](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.blas.dger.html#scipy.linalg.blas.dger) routine lists the arguments without much detail. They are automatically generated from the function's signature and do not carry much more meaning, it is expected that the user is aware of how the corresponding blas routine works *and* how f2py works.

The [signature for dger](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/fblas_l2.pyf.src#L225) uses `intent(in,out,copy)` meaning that the original argument is untouched (due to `copy`) and that the return value of `a` from the Fortran subroutine is made into the return value of the Python-level function.

So, there is not much you can do here to solve your problem. (WRONG, see EDIT)

EDIT: all the above is true except that f2py will place the output in a if the ordering (Fortran) and dtype of a match the expected output, see the original poster self-reply.

Comment: For reference, [NetLib reference manual](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d15/group__double__blas__level2_ga458222e01b4d348e9b52b9343d52f828.html#ga458222e01b4d348e9b52b9343d52f828) should be used since as you mentioned SciPy only wraps the low-level Fortran routines and adds docs only for the public API functions.

Comment: @percusse I was using the doc from [Intel][1] for BLAS, is there any difference? And I'm a bit confused, LAPACK includes BLAS? I've always thought of them as two different things


  [1]: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468390

Comment: @P.Camilleri Netlib has the reference implementations that have been tested for decades. LAPACK and BLAS are these reference implementations from the same group (or better consortium). There are also other implementations of these code. OpenBLAS, MKL, Accelerate etc are the architecture specific optimized versions which aim to boost the performance exploiting features specific to machines.